# Cef Compilation 64 bit Binaries not generated for Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, chromium-embedded

**CEF :**

**Branch : 2987**

**Terminal Commands for Generating binary distrib files after all the data gets downloaded**

```
$ export GYP_DEFINES=proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome

$ python /Users/imfinity/Documents/CEF_2987/automate/automate-git.py  --download-dir=/Users/imfinity/Documents/CEF_2987/download --branch=2987 --x64-build --force-config --force-build

$ cd /Users/imfinity/-dir/chromium/src/cef/tools

$ ./make_distrib.sh --ninja-build
```

**ERROR** : Traceback (most recent call last):

File "make_distrib.py", line 468, in

raise Exception('Missing generated header file: %s' % include)

Exception: Missing generated header file: cef_pack_resources.h

This leads to creation of : Incomplete Folder : cef_binary_3.2987.1574.g4232c4c_macosx32

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this command

```
$ export GYP_DEFINES=proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome

$ python /Users/imfinity/Documents/CEF_20March/automate/automate-git.py --download-dir /Users/imfinity/Documents/CEF_20March/download --branch=2987 --x64-build --force-config
```

and finally it worked and 64 bit binaries were generated

still surprised it worked after 5 different attempts!!!